# Couldn't find any package by regex in python:3.8.3 docker image

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, apt-get

I'm new to docker and I created a docker image and this is how my docker file looks like.

```
FROM python:3.8.3

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get install -y gcc libtool-ltdl-devel xmlsec1-1.2.20 xmlsec1-devel-1.2.20 xmlsec1 openssl- 
    1.2.20 xmlsec1-openssl-devel-1.2.20 \
    && apt-get -y install curl gnupg \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x  | bash - \
    && apt-get -y install nodejs 

WORKDIR /app/

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r production_requirements.txt \
    && front_end/noa-frontend/npm install
```

This image is used in docker-compose.yml's app service. So when I run the docker-compose build, I'm getting the below error saying it couldn't find the package. Those are few dependencies which I want to install in order to install a python package.

[image]

In the beginning, I've run the apt-get update to update the package lists.

Can anyone please help me with this issue.

**Updated Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8.3

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client\
    && apt-get install -y gcc libtool-ltdl-devel xmlsec1-1.2.20 xmlsec1- 
    devel-1.2.20 xmlsec1 openssl-1.2.20 xmlsec1-openssl-devel-1.2.20 \
    && apt-get -y install curl gnupg \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x  | bash - \
    && apt-get -y install nodejs

WORKDIR /app/

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r production_requirements.txt \
    && front_end/noa-frontend/npm install
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `apt-get install` after doing `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`. That is guaranteed not to end well. Try removing the `rm` command initially to see if that helps. If you really need to keep the size of the image down then put the `rm` command as the very last command in the run statement.

If you really want to reduce your image size then try switching to using `python:3.8-slim` or `python:3.8-alpine`. Alpine is a different OS to the default of Ubuntu, but its package manager can be told not to cache files locally. eg.

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-client
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc libtool-ltdl-devel xmlsec1-1.2.20 xmlsec1-devel-1.2.20 xmlsec1 \
    openssl-1.2.20 xmlsec1-openssl-devel-1.2.20
RUN apk add --no-cache curl gnupg
RUN apk add --no-cache  nodejs 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x  | bash -


WORKDIR /app/

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r production_requirements.txt \
    && front_end/noa-frontend/npm install
```

Certain bits of software might be available under different package names, so you'll have to check that out.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I will try what you have told. :)

Comment: I have removed the rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* this and try building the image, but still facing the same issue. I'll update the current Dockerfile in my question :(

I feel the package names might be different. I will check that

Comment: the packages which I was using were for yum repository, so for Ubuntu distribution, it was different. so after using the correct packages I was able to run docker-compose build successfully.

Answer (score 3):

The instruction `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` is more or less negating `apt-get update`. APT is no longer able to access the list of available packages after that. Move the `rm` to the end (and perhaps consider using the safer `apt-get clean all`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me where do i need to move the rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* or apt-get clean. You mean after RUN command?

Comment: I suggest behind the last `apt-get` call in your first `RUN` stanza.

Comment: Okay, will try and let you know :)

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue. I'll update the Dockerfile in the question